# What answer to make on OPTIONS request in CRUD on Django?

Tags: python, django, crud

I have code that handles django requests. It must respond to user requests. He has registered answers to POST and GET requests. But the frontend sends an options request, and it makes no response. What should I prescribe?

```
 @csrf_exempt
    def user_api(request, email=""):
        # if request.method == "GET":
        #     users = User.objects.all()
        #     users_serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        #     return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data, safe=False)
    
        # if email is not specified in address line by http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/some-email
        # then django returns data of ALL objects in json
        print(email)
        print(request.method)
        if request.method=="OPTIONS":
            return
        
        if email == "" and request.method == "GET":
            users = User.objects.all()
            users_serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data, safe=False)
    
        elif email == "" and request.method == "POST":
            user_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
            if user_serializer.is_valid():
                user_serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse("New user was created successfully", safe=False)
            else:
                return JsonResponse("Failed to create user", safe=False)
    
        else:
            # search the specified email and return data in json
            if request.method == "POST":
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                    user_serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=False)
                    print(user_serializer.data)
                    return JsonResponse(user_serializer.data, safe=False)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    return JsonResponse("User does not exists", safe=False)
    
            elif request.method == "PUT":
                user_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
                user = User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])  # щоб знати конкретного юзера, інфу якого змінюватимемо
                user_serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=user_data)
                if user_serializer.is_valid():
                    user_serializer.save()
                    return JsonResponse("User information was updated successfully", safe=False)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse("Failed to update user information", safe=False)
    
            elif request.method == "DELETE":
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                user.delete()
                return JsonResponse("User account was deleted successfully", safe=False)
```

Comment: because you are not returning anything on `OPTIONS` request